# Get body id using DOMXpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath, this, domxpath

Yes, I realize that you can use javascript/jQuery to do this, but I want to use PHP (it's more a learning thing). I can't install queryPath or phpQuery since this is on a client's webhost.

Basically I'm modifying

```
    function getElementById($id) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->domDocument);
    return $xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0);
}
```

to use, but

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in blahblahblah on line #
```

get thrown and `$this` is undefined.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the body id value of the same page the PHP is on.

Any ideas?

Comment: queryPath and phpQuery shouldn't need installing -- they're just PHP files that need to be included.  More pertinently to your question, you're using `$this`, which refers to the current object, when apparently you aren't using object oriented code.  Perhaps you could give a wider context for your code, in particular where `domDocument` is set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he is trying to just make a function to do some of this xpath stuff easier.

Something like

```
<?php
function getElementById($id,$url){

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHtmlFile($url); //Pull the contents at a URL, or file name

$xpath = new DOMXPath($html); // So we can use XPath...

return($xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0)); // Return the first item in element matching our id.

}

?>
```

I didn't test this, but it looks about right.